# How to do error handling more effectively in PHP with OOP?

Tags: php, api, oop

i'm trying to build my own restAPI so i have to response some http errors if there should be. I created a class called Response and i can use the properties in different php files in try catch method and  i can response the errors. But while i am doing that, i always create a response object and use the properties that i need from response class. Here is a little example of that :

```
if(array_key_exists("newsid",$_GET)){

    $news_id = $_GET['newsid'];

    if($news_id == '' || !is_numeric($news_id)){

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setHttpStatusCode(400);
        $response->setSuccess(false);
        $response->addMessage("Haber id'si boş olamaz veya sayı olmalı!");
        $response->send();
        exit;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
    //Gets a Single News
        try{
            $stmt = $readDB->prepare("SELECT id,title,details,poster_link FROM tb_news WHERE id = :id"); //syntax for prepared statements and PDO.
            $stmt->bindParam(':id',$news_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

            if($rowCount === 0){
                //Set up response for unsuccessful return
                $response = new Response();
                $response->setHttpStatusCode(404);
                $response->setSuccess(false);
                $response->addMessage("Haber Bulunamadı");
                $response->send();
                exit;
            }
```

As you see here, every time i control some condition, i create a response object and using the properties one by one and send the response. So how can i do it more effectively in my case? Can you give me some examples on that because i'm new to programming i can think about the logic but i can't mirror in my codes. I'm looking forward to hear your advices.

Comment: If you have code that you need repeatedly you can put it in a function/method.

Comment: Should i create the method in my Response class?

Comment: Where ever you feel it is appropriate. You could then do `(new Response())->sendError("Haber Bulunamadı");`. Or you could put in the class, or one of its parent classes, you're using at the moment: `$this->sendErrorResponse("Haber Bulunamadı");`.

Comment: You can look at most common frameworks how it's implemented. E.g. [Symfony Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i understand what should i do it but how should i show my httpResponse codes in it? i mean if it is a database query error and when i send ```$this->sendErrorResponse("Database connection error"); ``` ,how should i print the 500 error code with it like in my code?

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for advice, but i'm trying to learn pure PHP fully and OOP basics then i will write the same project with framework such as laravel or other ones.

Comment: @AtaBerkYılmaz Justinas does not say 'USE laravel', they mean take a look at the code of that framework, see how request/response is implemented there for inspiration and education :)

Comment: @TomRegner but the question is not how request/response is implemented but "How to do error handling". Besides, it's almost impossible to use an established codebase to get an "inspiration", because it's so much decomposed that one looking from outside just cannot get the gist. It takes one enormous effort to understand such a big codebase.

Comment: @AtaBerkYılmaz note that you don't need anything like `$this->sendErrorResponse("Database connection error");`. this kind of errors will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are used exactly for that.

First, create a custom exception,

```
class HttpException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Then change your code to

```
if($news_id == '' || !is_numeric($news_id)){
    throw new HttpException("Haber id'si boş olamaz veya sayı olmalı!", 400);
}
```

Then write an [Exception handler](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) (as you need one anyway) and add a condition in the processing results

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setSuccess(false);
if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
    $response->setHttpStatusCode($e->getCode());
    $response->addMessage($e->getMessage());
} else { // a default error handler
    error_log($e);
    $response->setHttpStatusCode(500);
    $response->addMessage("Server error");
}
$response->send();
exit;
```

Just remember that you don't need any code to send a "Database connection error". First, it's nobody's business, whether it's a database error or anything else. All they have to get is just a "Server error". And second, your database API will already throw an Exception in case of error, so all you need is to catch it in the error handler.

Comment: Just a quick question, the exception handler part, where should i use exactly? in HttpException class?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#function

Comment: Also should i use in a method?

Comment: Exception handler is a function. That you have to write somewhere.